# Power Diophantine Equation: $ax^n-by^m=1$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

I found literature for  $ax^n-by^n=1$ (R. A. Mollin, D. T. Walker) but I am looking for results of the equation  $ax^n-by^m=1$.

Does $ax^n-by^m=1$ has infinite solution? How do we find them?

Please provide related literature/reference if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's a special case of [Pillai's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Pillai's_conjecture) which is a generalization of Catalan's conjecture. Recently, Bernett proved the remarkable result [here](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/B-CJM-Pillai.pdf) in 2002 that

Let d be an integer with d > 3 and let a, b be positive with $d \geq 3$ and $a,b$ be positive integers. Then the equation 
$$|ax^d-by^d|=1$$
has at most 1 solution.

Generally, these equations motivate from [Thue's equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation)

Comment: Pillai's conjecture  does not have non power coefficient $a, b$

Comment: You mean your equation in 4 unknowns $a,b,x,y$?

Comment: No $a, b$ are constant.

Comment: It means you fix $a,b,m,n$ in your equation?

Comment: Yes , those are fixed, $x, y$  are variables